# C free garbages char pointer

Tags: c, free, scanf

I doing some text-extraction in C and getting some 'garbage-strings' when i call
free on my loop. Here is some sample text:

```
Sentence #1 (34 tokens):
The Project Gutenberg EBook of Moby Dick; or The Whale, by Herman Melville

This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with
almost no restrictions whatsoever.
[Text=The CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=3 PartOfSpeech=DT Lemma=the]                     [Text=Project CharacterOffsetBegin=4 CharacterOffsetEnd=11 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=project]
```

## Question:

1 - Can i safely reuse the pointer variable after free it?

Thanks for any help!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define LINE_M (1024*100)

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

        FILE *file;
        char buff[LINE_M];
        char *lemma;
        char *text;
        char *sentence = NULL;
        char *p, *t;
        int numSent, numTok;

        file = fopen("moby.txt.out", "r");


        while (fgets(buff, LINE_M, file))
        {
        if(sscanf(buff, "Sentence #%d (%d tokens):", &numSent, &numTok))
            continue;

        if(strstr(buff, "[Text=") == NULL)
        {
            if(sentence != NULL)
            {
            sentence = realloc(sentence, (strlen(buff) + strlen(sentence) + 2) * sizeof(char));
            strcat(sentence, buff);
            }
            else
            {
            sentence = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buff) + 1));
            strcpy(sentence, buff);
            }

            continue;
        }
        p = buff;
        while ((p = strstr(p, "Text=")) != NULL)
        {

            p += 5;
            t = strchr(p, ' ');

            text = malloc((int)(t - p));
            strncpy(text, p, (int)(t - p));

            p = strstr(t + 1, "Lemma=") + 6;
            t = strchr(p, ']');

            lemma = malloc((int)(t - p) * sizeof(char));
            strncpy(lemma, p, (int)(t - p));

            p = t + 1;

            printf("%s\n", lemma);
            free(text);
            free(lemma);

            text = NULL;
            lemma = NULL;

        } 
        free(sentence);
        sentence = NULL;

        }

        fclose(file);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's not OK to reuse the memory pointed to by a freed pointer, but it's perfectly fine to store a new pointer in the same slot of memory where you stored your old one that you freed. (I'm pretty sure what you were asking about was the 2nd case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the string you are copying are not null terminated and when printed might include garbage chars.

from `man strncpy`:

The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied. Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest **will not be null-terminated**.

Comment: strings are not `NULL` terminated but null terminated.

Comment: If you want to be that pedantic: they are `'\0'`-terminated.

Comment: Actually I think that NUL is most appropriate but i changed it anyway. Thanks.